# Bitmap size after using BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream) to create a bitmap. But the size of the bitmap returned by bitmap.getByteCount() is coming out be very huge compared to the actual image size. The actual image size when I download(on disk) is around 36kb, but the bitmap generated has a size of around 800kb. Since it is the same image, how come there is such a huge difference ? I am using the following piece of code.
Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 is helping me to reduce the size of the image

```
public Bitmap downloadImage(String imageUrl) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        inputStream = (new URL(imageUrl)).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
            Log.d("downloadImage","size of downloaded image " + bitmap.getByteCount()/1024);
        return bitmap;
    }  catch (Exception e) {
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: A Bitmap is a raw image without any compression - of course its going to be huge.

Comment: When you download the image on your computer or save it somewhere you probably use jpg or png as image format and both are very very good at compressing images.